# Array value store to each treenode and then access them

Tags: c#

```
TreeNode ns = new TreeNode("Main"); 

public void selectInput(string inp)
{ 
    //  values and input array  length are same
    string[] values={"asd","qwe","qwer"};
    string[] store_arr = inp.Split('|');
    for(int i=0;i<store_arr.length;i++)
    {
        ns.Nodes.Add(store_arr[i].ToString()); 
        ns.Tag = values[i].ToString();
    }
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(ns);
}
```

I want to store each treenode value separately and then i want to access these values by drag drop on listbox

Comment: store different values to each subnode ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Add` method support adding key and text so just use that overload.. you also should check if you have enough items in the hardcoded `values` array to avoid nasty runtime errors. Final code can look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < store_arr.length; i++)
{
   string value = (i < values.Length) ? values[i] : "";
   ns.Nodes.Add(value, store_arr[i]);
}
```

This will create nodes with `name` equal to the value - to access that name (meaning your custom value) simply have `ns.Nodes[index].Name`

Comment: this is not that i am asking i am asking it will show some treenode text on treeview and each treenode store some index of an valus_array

Comment: @Malik Yes it is. It will store each value in each tree node while still showing the text from the given `inp` string. Storing it as the `Tag` is meaningless and not the correct way.

Comment: can u please tell me how can i acess the treenode value

Comment: can u plz tell me what is the purpose of tag property in treeview when we use tag property

Comment: @Malik the value is actually its Name to access it use `ns.Name` where "ns" is instance of TreeNode. Tag is a "joker" it has no specific purpose and used to store general information about the object. Good description is given in the official documentation under the "Remarks" section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx

Answer (score 0):

strong textTreeNode ns = new TreeNode("Main");

public void selectInput(string inp)
{ 
    //  values and input array  length are same
    string[] values={"asd","qwe","qwer"};
    string[] store_arr = inp.Split('|');
    for(int i=0;i

Comment: ?? What is it? If this code is somehow relevant edit your original question with it and explain how it's related.